# WordPress ACL (folder + permissions)

Tags: admin, security, directory, server

For certificate a web platform created with WordPress, they ask me to provide a snapshot of ACL maintained on application / configuration folder.

Screenshot must clearly show who all have access to the folder and with what permissions.

Where can I found this? I'm using wordpress and server with WHM/Cpanel.

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WordPress. It's regarding the filesystem on the server. Contact your host.